# how to monitor EventLoop's I/O thread

Tags: netty, event-loop

I have a server built with Netty. Recently i encounter an issue may caused by I/O thread blocking.

I tried to add a LoggingHanlder to the pipeline,

```
socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
```

and figure out the eventloop's I/O thread blocked for almost one minute.

I want to find out why did the thread block,but i can't get any log about eventloop's underlying behavior such as select,processSelectedKeys and run all tasks.

Several code reviews are done,and i am pretty sure that all time-consuming jobs are submitted to a self-defined Executor.

**If I would like to monitor activity of eventloop something like select,processSelectedKeys and RunAllTask,How should I do?**

The png below illustrates the EventLoop's behavior.
[NioEventLoop behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mOIt.png)

Comment: I read the java docs and figure out  LoggingHandler just Logs a io.netty.channel.ChannelEvent for debugging purpose.But i want more logs about netty's eventloop, what should i do?